# IIS / ASP / Static content: restrict access to directory content with guard

Tags: c#, asp.net, authorization, iis-6

I'm looking for a solution concerning access restrictions using IIS6, a ASP.NET website (**SiteA**, FW 2.0) and a website with static content (**SiteB**):

### The Problem / Preconditions:

- A user authenticated to **SiteA** should be able to access the static
  content of **SiteB**
- Non-authenticated access to **SiteB** should be
  redirected to **SiteA**'s login script
- Because **SiteA** is legacy code it
  doesn't use any of ASP.NET's authentication mechanisms. There is a
  method `IsAuthenticated() = true/false` which checks authentication
  status for **SiteA**.
- I'm still free to place **SiteB** anywhere (depending
  on solution): in **SiteA**'s directory structure or somewhere else, maybe
  on another server

### Considered Solution / How it could work:

- **SiteB** is placed in **SiteA** directory structure (e.g. `SiteA-Root/subfolder/SiteB-Root`)
- IIS should intercept requests to directory `SiteA-Root/subfolder/SiteB-Root`
- IIS allows access if `IsAuthenticated == true` for each request to `SiteA-Root/subfolder/SiteB-Root`
- IIS redirects to **SiteA**'s login page otherwise

### What I've tried yet:

- Using IIS-UrlRewrite and redirect any request to **SiteB** to a guard script, e.g. `SiteA/Interceptor.aspx?referer=<Url of requested content of SiteB>`
- `Interceptor.aspx` loads `<Url of requested content of SiteB>` if `IsAuthenticated() == true` or redirects to the login page otherwise
- `Interceptor.aspx` writes the loaded stream to it's own response
- Problems:

  - any relative link in the loaded **SiteB** page doesn't work anymore -> requires parsing(?)
  - heavy processing because any request to **SiteB** is handled by `Interceptor.aspx`

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if static content is the issue , make it a Virtual directory within the Web Application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with IIS 6.0 ( or anything pre IIS7.0), is that it does not support requests for static contents go through the ASP.NET life cycle. And hence you cannot access the events defined in Global.asax and other ASP.NET features such as authentication/authorization.

But I guess there is a way to override that behavior, as explained in this post: http://www.devtoolshed.com/globalasax-events-iis-6-and-iis-7-static-resources

So, once you have configured this to pass the requests through the ASP.NET lifecycle, isn't it possible to capture the request in one of those appropriate Global.asax events, and then set a Session value that this request is already authenticated or not? You can use proper Forms Authentication as well.

So if a request comes for the static content (which is a part of the sub folder in SiteA itself), all you have to check (in one of the events in Global.asax) if the request is already authenticated for the session, if not redirect to login form. Since you are doing a pass-through in-case it is already authenticated, you shouldnt be having broken links as well.

Comment: That doesn't solve the entire problem but points me to the right direction.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your insights once you solved your problem. I also intended to point you to the right direction based on my understanding of the problem..Thanks

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18999735/fire-events-for-requests-to-static-content-without-setting-runallmanagedmodulesf