# Fire events for requests to static content without setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config, iis-6, static-content

I'm looking for a more precise solution to handle requests for static contents by the ASP.NET lifecycle without setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true.
As far as I know is the effect of `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = "true"` that the precondition attribute of each module will be set to `""`.

### The problem:

- I have to protect static content in a subfolder of a web application against unauthorized access
- To include requests to those static contents in the ASP.NET lifecycle and therefore having some events fired, I set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to `true` in web.config.
- Because this solution turns the big wheel and all managed modules are affected for the whole application, I'm looking for a more adapted solution restricted to the subfolder where this behavior is required.
- I need a solution for IIS6 and II7

### Question 1:

The preconditon of which modules have to be resetted (`precondition = ""`) to fire global.asax.cs events (e.g. `Application_BeginRequest`) for requests for static contents?

### Question 2:

Is it possible to limit this request handling to requests to a single subfolder (e.g. perhaps by placing an adapted web.config in this subfolder, tweeking the main web.config, ...)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought in the direction of registering a custom HttpModule for the right event of global.asax, and then enabling the HttpModule only for the sub directory using `location` attribute in the main `web.config` itself? It is just a thought of a possible solution - I havent thought through it..

```
<location path="subDirectoryPath">
   <system.web>
     <httpmodules>
        <add type="MyCustomModule.Name" name="MyCustomModule" />      
     </httpmodules>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

EDIT:

You may have to override your web.config, and bring in all the httpModule section in this, and then insert the custom module at the right place, with the right precondition.
This is to avoid setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to true

Comment: Hi Abey, doesn't that require setting runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests = true to catch non-managed handlers like .html etc., too?

Comment: Not really. You will have to find out the right module which has to enable request processing for static contents. For ex, if you are looking for Forms Authentication to be applied for static content, remove the precondition of only that module.<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know: 'the name(s) of the right module(s)' should be the answer to question 1.

Comment: Hehe - That is exactly what you should be researching and finding out mate!. This is the general idea towards solving your problem. My gut feeling is that you should be targeting the `FormsAuthentication module` if you are using Forms Auth or `WindowsAuth` incase otherwise. In any case the event should be **`PostAuthenticateRequest event`**. Please go through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.ASPX) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.ASPX) to find out which events to target.